# Кракозябры на apple устройствах в php Форме

Tags: php

Всем привет, при отправке формы поле echo на apple устройствах отображается криво

```
<?php
if((isset($_POST['name'])&&$_POST['name']!="")&&(isset($_POST['email'])&&$_POST['email']!="")&&(isset($_POST['phone'])&&$_POST['phone']!="")){

$to = 'godofwar9325@gmail.com'; //Почта получателя, через запятую можно указать сколько угодно адресов
        $subject = 'Обратный звонок'; //Загаловок сообщения
        $message = '
                <html>
                    <head>
                        <title>'.$subject.'</title>
                    </head>
                    <body>
                        <p><b>Имя:</b> '.$_POST['name'].'</p>
                        <p><b>Телефон:</b> '.$_POST['phone'].'</p> 
                         <p><b>Почта:</b> '.$_POST['email'].'</p>                         
                    </body>
                </html>'; //Текст нащего сообщения можно использовать HTML теги
        $headers  = "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8 \r\n"; //Кодировка письма
        $headers .= "From: Отправитель <uber-key.ru>\r\n"; //Наименование и почта отправителя

        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

        echo "<center><h2>Заявка отправлена, мы свяжемся с Вами в течении 15 минут.</h2>";


 //Отправка письма с помощью функции mail


}?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам в предыдущем вопросе ответили. чарсет для файла, в котором эхаете не выставлен.

Если рисуете структуру:

```
<head>
   ...
   <meta charset="utf-8" /> 
   ...
</head>
```

И без:

```
<?php
   header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Последнее в самом начале файла, после открывающего тега